# Find the algorithm used to make the next number in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence

The first number in a sequence is 0094332543029476 and the next number in the sequence is 0094332543031698.
We know the difference between the two is 2222 and GDC is 2.
I need to know the next number in the sequence. (And it's not 0094332543033920 after adding 2222). and it is also not 0094332543049474 by using 0094332543029476 + 2222*3^2.

The number of digits is fixed (16), the next number in the sequence is always positive and bigger than the previous one.

This means that some operation has been done to the first number which gives us 2222 as the number to add to make the second one.

There is an algorithm being applied to the first number(0094332543029476) (or its individual digits) to produce 2222 to be added and make the next one. Now this same algorithm must be applied to 0094332543031698 to produce the third number and so on.

This means that it is not based on 2222 and that there is an algorithm involved.

How would you approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are *literally* an infinite number of answers.

Comment: (We also know that it is not random, and that it is always a higher value than the previous number)

Comment: My guess is that calculations have been done to the individual digits of each number in order to produce 2222 as the number to add to make the next one in the sequence.

Comment: How would you go about verifying that guess, and (for example) rule out all of the possibilities that @Elliot identified?

Comment: Because it is stated that there is only one possible answer to the problem. 
The sequence never ends, and the next number only has one value. It cannot be infinite. Therefore I think that some operation between individual digits (maybe between odds&even) has been done in order to produce an "add 2222" order.

Comment: There are an infinite number of strictly ascending sequences that start with the 2 values you provide but not the third, and you have provided *no* basis for choosing one over another.

Comment: That is exactly why I think there is an algorithm involved which does a series of calculations to 0094332543029476 (meaning, to every individual digit) in order to produce 0094332543031698 as the next number, which is strangely 2222 numbers apart and therefore means nothing to the next number in the sequence since 2222 has ben produces BY the first number in the sequence.
It is the result of a computer program and not just a "simple" math problem.

Comment: I have 2 such algorithms in mind which meet your description; how do I tell which is correct?

Comment: Do you? Maybe we should try both. I have been trying for ages whithout any luck.
The program will tell me if the answer is correct.

Comment: @ScottHunter , would you please share those proposed algorithms? 
The post has been closed, I don't know if you can answer via comments, I am new here.

Comment: @SamuelCheca, literally any number greater than `S(1) = 94332543031698` is a legitimate solution (except for `S(1) + 2222`). You must try to understand that your problem doesn't make sense (you're asking for a unique solution that doesn't exist). I've provided a proof of this for you in my answer.

Comment: I know for a fact that there is only one possible answer. This is why I know there is an algorithm involved since the only other data we know is that 2222 is the increment (produced by a calculation on the first number.
It would be great if @ScottHunter could hep with those two proposed algorithms.

Comment: @SamuelCheca, if you read my answer it will explain how you can find any number of solutions. I'll provide two explicitly: `fz(n) = 94332543029476 + 2222*n^z`, `f2(2) = 94332543038364`, `f3(2) = 94332543047252`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer but it is not correct or accepted by the program. 
The fact that there is a difference between the two of 2222, does not affect on the calculation of the next number.
There must be some sort of algorithm involved, the numbers look like 2of5 interleaved barcode numbers. However the Luhn algorithm or mod10 (same as on credit card numbers) is not working. Check digit is also not valid. Plus this would not generate the new consecutive number.

Comment: I think the answer goes along the lines of Lagged Fibonacci generators, Linear feedback shift registers, Linear congruential generators, Middle square method and algorithms generating consecutive numbers but I cannot find out which method has been used.
@ScottHunter

Comment: This is a very similar problem to mine on reverse engineering the algorithm used on on a list of consecutive pseudo random generated numbers :
https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/m6c5d/can_pseudo_randomly_generated_numbers_be_reverse/

Comment: It most certainly is a type of linear congruential generator.Any idea on the two possible algorithms? @ScottHunter. I would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @ScottHunter, Could you help me out with those two algorithms?

Comment: Not until/unless the question gets re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a bit of renaming:

We're looking for a sequence, `S(n)`:

`S(0)  = 94332543029476`
`S(1)  = S(0) + 2222`
`S(2) != S(1) + 2222`

and the sequence is strictly increasing.
(ie: `S(i) < S(j)`, when `i < j`)

We want to find the value that corresponds to the ***only possible value of*** `S(2)`.

Short answer: **The constraints on the sequence are insufficient to restrict the value of `S(2)` to just one value**:

Lets consider a family of unique sequences, `fz(n)`:

`fz(n) = n^z`, Where `z` is an integer greater than one.

This implies that:

`fz(0) = 0^z = 0`
`fz(1) = 1^z = 1`
`fz(2) = 2^z > 2`

Also, for each value of `z`, this generates a unique sequence:
`fi(2) < fj(2)` when `i < j`

So now lets consider a family of unique sequences, `gz(n)`:

`gz(n) = S0 + 2222*fz(n)`

...which implies:

`gz(0) = S(0)`
`gz(1) = S(0) + 2222 = S(1)`
`gz(2) > S(0) + 2*2222` => `gz(2) != S(1) + 2222`

Hence for every `z` integer greater than 1, there's a unique solution, `gz(2)`.

So, as `Scott Hunter` pointed out in the comments: Not only does this problem not have a unique solution, it also has an unlimited amount of solutions.

More broadly, if you choose any value for `S(2)` greater than `S(1)` (except for `S(1) + 2222`), then there will always be an unlimited amount of sequences that generates `S(0)`, `S(1)` and `S(2)` correctly (you can extend my above proof to show this, but it isn't necessary to answer your question).

There simply needs to be more information / constraints around the sequence.

Even if we knew that it was a polynomial, and even if we had access to the first `k` elements of the sequence, then there is only a unique solution to a `k-th order` polynomial, and an infinite number of solutions for any polynomial larger than `k-th order` (possibly no solution for polynomials less than `k-th order`).

Another way to say it is that because there aren't enough constraints on the solution, the `degrees of freedom` are unbound, and so will always be more than any data samples that you might provide. You can [read more about that here](https://www.et.byu.edu/%7Erowley/ChEn273/Topics/Mass_Balances/Single_Unit_Mass_Balance/Deg_of_Freedom_Introduction.htm).

Comment: Or 2222 (the only one of the 3 values actually appearing in the question)?

Comment: -Sorry I made a mistake, the second number in the sequence is 0094332543031698 instead of 0094332543021698.

What would be one possible answer ?

Comment: @SamuelCheca: `S(n) = 94332543029476 + 2222*n^2`

Comment: @SamuelCheca, use the formula: `S(2) = 94332543029476 + 2222*2^2 = 94332543038364`.